# prefetchInfiniteQuery returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I use `prefetchInfiniteQuery` on my Next.js app, inside `getServerSideProps`, and it returns undefined. I'm not sure if it's normal ? My data is correctly loaded from `useInfiniteQuery()` and I can see all the next fetch but I want to prefetch on the server side so I'm using the [hydration methode](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr).

**This is my app.js file extract**:

```
import { QueryClientProvider, QueryClient } from 'react-query';
const queryClient = new QueryClient()

MyApp ({ Component, pageProps, user_account_menu, userProfile, token, fallback }){
    return (
      
        <>
            <DefaultSeo {...SEO}/>
            <FacebookPixel />
            <SWRConfig value={{ fallback }}>
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <GlobalStyles />
                <BreakPointProvider>
                <AuthProvider>
                <DisplayProvider>
                <EcommerceProvider>
                  
                  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                  <Header 
                    principal_menu={fallback.principal_menu}  
                    menu_sections={fallback.menu_sections}
                    user_account_menu={user_account_menu}
                    token={token} 
                    userProfile={userProfile} 
                  />
                      <Component {...pageProps} token={token} reviews={fallback.reviews}  newsletter={fallback.newsletter}/>
                    
                  </QueryClientProvider>
                  <PopUpNewsletter newsletter={fallback.newsletter} />
                  <Footer footer_menu={fallback.footer_menu} reviews={fallback.reviews} policies={fallback.policies_menu}/>
                </EcommerceProvider>
                </DisplayProvider>
                </AuthProvider>
                </BreakPointProvider>
              </ThemeProvider>
            </SWRConfig>
        </>
    )
}
```

**my index.js page file  (SSR)** :

```
import { useQuery, useQueryClient, useInfiniteQuery, dehydrate, QueryClient, Hydrate } from 'react-query';

const getProviders = async (key, pageParam = 0) => {
  ...
  return queryProps
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()

  const { query } = ctx;
  const { page = 1 } = query;

  const token = parseCookies(ctx).jwt ? parseCookies(ctx).jwt : null
  
  const limit = 16;
  const start = +page === 1 ? 0 : (+page - 1) * limit
  const configSimple = 'simple'

  let resProviders
  
  if(!token){
    resProviders = await fetchAPI(getTalentCards);
  }else{
    resProviders = await fetchAuthorizationAPI(getTalentCards, token, configSimple);
  }
    const providersData = await resProviders;
  

   ... all props fetched

  const providers = {
    pages: [
      { 
        result: providersData,
        pageId: 0,
        dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
      }
    ],
    pageParams: [0],
  }

  return {
    props: {
      providers: providers,
      page: +page,
      provider_types: providerTypesData,
      countries: countriesData,
      cities: citiesData,
      provider_statuses: providerStatusesData,
      start,
      limit,
      token: token
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s expected and documented here: https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientprefetchquery

> prefetchQuery is an asynchronous method that can be used to prefetch a query before it is needed or rendered with useQuery and friends. The method works the same as fetchQuery except that it will not throw or return any data.

If you want data returned, you can use `fetchQuery`, but for hydration, you don’t need to. Prefetching will put the data in the cache and then you can send the cache to the client. There is also an example in the docs that does it exactly like that: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr#using-hydration

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
   const queryClient = new QueryClient()
 
   await queryClient.prefetchQuery('posts', getPosts)
 
   return {
     props: {
       dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
     },
   }
 }
```